# Officially stepping down as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

I know it's been a while so it's not going to be any surprise to hear that I'm handing in my diamond.

As for reasons, it's multifaceted. Certainly I got burnt out on a lot of issues (handling the system tagging issue and the unprotection debacle specifically). However, life also threw me some fun stuff in the form of COVID, and a divorce, depression, and a new relationship. A big factor though is that I stopped playing D&D and all its offshoots and editions quite a while ago, which greatly reduced the amount of things that actively pulled me into engagement on the site.

Regardless though, I considered my experience moderating here positive and, if things change for me, I won't put out the possibility of going for a diamond again in the future if the site will still have me.

I do want to thank the community for electing me and giving me the chance to be your moderator. I think this is a wonderful community and I was lucky to be able to have been your moderator. I hope the community continues to grow and get better.

I won't be deleting my account or anything like that of course, and I'll likely be around very occasionally.

If anybody wanted to contact me, currently the best way to do so is on Discord at rubiksmoose#9728.

Comment: Thank you for everything you've done for us.

Comment: obligatory downvote (also because sad).

Comment: @goodguy5 it feels like a downvote says they should stay on and ignore their other commitments...?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage it's an old callback joke to moose and I saying that we'd downvote each other's posts. Also the meta points don't matter so I wasn't too concerned about it.

Comment: @goodguy5 ahh good to know :p

Comment: I'd give another + if I could for "multifaceted".

Comment: I hope your future sees you well and we'll see you around!

Answer (score 43):

Well, I for one would like to say

## Thank You!

You did an excellent job by us, and we are grateful. All the best!

Answer (score 27):

### Thanks for being a great co-mod!

I'm sorry to see you step down as a moderator, but it's totally understandable – it can be a stressful role, and life must come first. You did a great job as moderator; I couldn't have been elected alongside anyone better. (And you're welcome to be reinstated as mod if you ever change your mind.)

Good luck in your future endeavors, and feel free to hit me up on Discord or elsewhere anytime! :)

Comment: Same back to you. It makes me happy that the site still has a group of excellent mods to take care of it.

Answer (score 18):

> I felt a great disturbance in the Force...

You have been with us for years. You have been a cornercube we could rely on. And you have been here for all of us. For that I want to wish you

> [So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojydNb3Lrrs)

While I feel tempted to ask you to

> [Please don't go. The Drones need you. They look up to you.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FZNPxmTB4o)

I will instead ask you to be the best you you can be and let me apologize for the mischief and grief and infighting the community had over the years. WE weren't always the most easy to handle, I know. So instead, let us part with one of the most magnificent messages a being could leave to someone else - and sorry to quote Douglas Andams twice, he is just too on point:

> The first letter was a “w”, the second an “e”. Then there was a gap. An “a” followed, then a “p”, an “o” and an “l”. Marvin paused for a rest. After a few moments they resumed and let him see the “o”, the “g”, the “i”, the “s” and the “e”. The next two words were “for” and “the”. The last one was a long one, and Marvin needed another rest before he could tackle it. It started with an “i”, then “n” then a “c”. Next came an “o” and an “n”, followed by a “v”, an “e”, another “n” and an “i”. After a final pause, Marvin gathered his strength for the last stretch. He read the “e”, the “n”, the “c” and at last the final “e”, and staggered back into their arms.

Comment: No need to appologize :) Managing a community is what I signed up for as a moderator and you definitely know there are going to be ups and downs. All-in-all I think this is a wonderful community and was actually one of the better ones out there to moderate.

Comment: still we can always try to do better

Comment: Definitely! Improvements can always be made. Things definitely aren't perfect lol

Answer (score 9):

### I must accept being Moose deprived

I have commented any number of times that I miss our beloved Moose, and I guess we'll miss you some more. I may send you a funny pic now and again on Discord.

Been great having you as part of the voices of reason for as long as you could offer us your most precious gift: your time.

Answer (score 5):

Rubiks,

Thanks so much for your service to the community.

I remember your amusing icon from my earliest days on RPG.SE.  No doubt there's some precipitating story involving a plastic gadget, a hiker taking a rest, a curious elk, and a flash of otherworldly magic....

Best wishes